# How to migrate MOSS 2007 portal into share point 2010?

Tags: 2007, migration

I have my company intranet portal in Moss 2007,i need to implement it into 2010,What are the possible way to do this.is that possible to restore the content data base in 2010 portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may make more sense to do an in-place upgrade depending on your hardware.  What you can do is run this command for a lot more info about your environment:

stsadm -o preupgradecheck

You can run this at any time.  It will not hurt anything.  It'll spit out a nice report about everything you'll need to migrate/fix or think about before the upgrade.  Do you have new hardware and moving to that or is an in-place upgrade feasible?

Answer (score 0):

Best place to start is the TechNet SharePoint Upgrade Planning Portal, it'll give you background to allt he areas you need to know in order to successfully and correctly plan and perform an upgrade.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx